# Build NET471 & netstandard 2.0 solution from the command line

Tags: msbuild, windows-10, .net-standard-2.0

Is it possible to compile a NET471 and netstandard (and netcoreapp) 2.0 solution from the command line?

I have a solution which contains netstandard 2.0 libraries, netcoreapp 2.0 projects, and WPF Net 4.7.1 Test Apps.

Now I've tried to build the solution two ways, but each way won't support the opposing framework.

**MSBuild**

```
MSBuild.exe .\MySolution.sln
```

Error on class libraries:

> C:\Development\TestLibrary.csproj(1,1): error MSB4041: The default XML
>   namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the
>   project is authored i n the MSBuild 2003 format, please add
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>    element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
>   1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

**DOTNET build**

```
dotnet build .\MyTestSolution.sln
```

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2925,5):
>   error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because
>   MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4"
>   and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime
>   and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the
>   required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\MSBuild.exe"
>   exists and can be run.
>   [C:\Development\MyTestApp.csproj]

Note: I don't want to add multiple framework targets to my NETStandard libraries (I've recently just ripped them out as of NET47), besides MSBuild doesn't seem to support the new csproj format.

Comment: Which msbuild are you using? are you running it from the developer command prompt? (the msbuild version 4 cannot build new project files, you need the one installed with VS 2017)

Comment: @MartinUllrich thanks, that's got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Martin Ullrich comment, I've figured it out.

[image: Original MSBuild location]

Add the latest MSBuild version

[image: Adjust PATH]

Restart my PowerShell and the correct version now shows

[image: Now using correct MSBuild version]